# How to create an Observable timer test in jasmine-marble?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, jasmine

I am not able to create a test to test a timer Observable in function startTimer. I use a 6.3.1 version of RXJS.

It's my code:

```
private createSubscribe(): void {
  if (this.timer) {
    this.subscription = this.timer.subscribe(() => {
      this.cream().then(() => {
        this.subscription.unsubscribe();
        this.subscription = null;
        this.timer = null;
        this.startTimer(this.config.period);
      });
    });
  }
}

private startTimer(period): void {
  if (period) {
    this.timer = timer(period * 1000);
    this.createSubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem using:

```
it('startTimer: should call createSubscribe and set timer with observable emited in 5000ms.', () => {

  const scheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
    expect(actual).toEqual(expected);
  });

  scheduler.run(helpers => {
    const { expectObservable } = helpers;
    const period = 5;
    const expected = '5000ms (a|)';
    spyOn(helper, <any>'createSubscribe');

    helper['startTimer'](period);

    expectObservable(helper['timer']).toBe(expected, {a : 0});
    expect(helper['createSubscribe']).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```